# How to restore python 2.7 in ubuntu after accidentally removal[messed up my /usr/bin/]

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt, tex-live

I was trying to repair texlive using the following script
http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh

this messed up my /usr/bin directory. Now I am getting this error

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Somehow now I dont have python 2.7.

Also sudo apt update does not work any more.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

How do I fix this errors

**Try 1:**

Downloaded python 2.7.6 ".tar" from official website and tried

```
./configure
```

Got Error

```
./configure.lineno: line 473: expr: command not found
```

echo $PATH

```
/home/USER/anaconda3/bin:/bin:/condabin:/home/USER/gv:/home/USER/bin:/home/USER/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/USER/g09/bsd:/home/USER/g09/local:/home/USER/g09/extras:/home/USER/g09
```

Comment: You can download python 2.7 from official website [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/), untar/unzip it and then build it using the instructions in README.rst file.

Comment: ./configure gives error. check my edited post.

Comment: Can you paste the output of the following command: `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: made edit to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to install ubuntu again. I installed ubuntu on same partition which had old ubuntu(messed up one) with out formatting the partition which preserves all the files are rewrites file which are essential for new install.

Hope this helps other who have same issue